# How to set image with effect in ImageButton before to click

Tags: java, android

I want to use the selected image to set the button with the effect of it, before clicking on it, and then clicking the effect applies the same image in ImageView, but the way it is, use the default image, not the image chosen.

```
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    btnSepia = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSepia);

    BitmapDrawable abmp = (BitmapDrawable) imgView.getDrawable();
    bmp = abmp.getBitmap();

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    i.setType("image/");

    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);


    final Drawable resSepia = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
    imgView.setImageDrawable(resSepia);

     Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (resSepia == null)
                return;
            final ColorMatrix matrixA = new ColorMatrix();
            // making image B&W
            matrixA.setSaturation(0);

            final ColorMatrix matrixB = new ColorMatrix();
            // applying scales for RGB color values
            matrixB.setScale(1f, .95f, .82f, 1.0f);
            matrixA.setConcat(matrixB, matrixA);

            final ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrixA);
            resSepia.setColorFilter(filter);

            btnSepia.setImageDrawable(resSepia);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

btnSepia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { 

            imgView.setImageDrawable(resSepia);

        }
    });
```

Thanks();

Sorry for my english is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get your question, as to what i can get through the description above, is that you want to change the image upon the action.

So you could use Selector, basically don't place your image source directly instead use a selector in image source.

To make a selector, define a selector.xml in resources., use this way:
`<selector>`(specify selector tag in xml) and under it define an item tag, which will have following properties

```
<selector>
<item 
    android:state="<Give_State_HERE>" 
    android:drawable="<GIVE_Source_of_Your_Drawable_Here"/> 
</selector>
```

Try this and specify this xml as your img:source., hope this helps